# How to combine tail and grep in linux

Tags: linux, shell, grep, tail

I can't tail the last n lines of a file on linux, likewise i can grep 
e.g `grep "2015-09-29 04:" filename.ext` 
But how can i combine both such that i display from a certain grep to the end of the file.

Comment: `cat file | grep "2015-09-29 04:" | tail` perhaps?  I don't have access to a Linux installation at the moment to test.

Comment: @EricJ.: UUoC — Useless Use of Cat?  And it only selects the lines that match.

Answer (score 4):

You don't use `grep` or `tail` any more.  You use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^2015-09-29 04:/,$p'
```

Don't print by default (`-n`).  From the first line starting `2015-09-29 04:` to the end of file (`$`), print the lines.

If you absolutely must use `grep` and you have GNU `grep`, then you could consider:

```
grep -A 999999999 -e '^2015-09-29 04:'
```

That prints the first billion or so lines after the first line that matches the pattern (and the counter resets if the pattern appears during that trailing material).  Of course, if your file is 2 billion lines long and the pattern occurs after a million lines (and never again), then you'll be missing a lot of data.

Comment: Plus 1.  For completeness, an awk solution: `awk '/^2015-09-29 04:/{f=1} f'`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
line_no=`grep -n -m1 "$1" $2 | cut -d: -f1`
echo "Starting at line: " $line_no
tail -n +$line_no $2
```

Usage: script 'text to hunt for' filename
e.g.

```
./grep.sh 'Sep 29 13:14' /var/log/syslog
```

- `-n` issue line numbers
- `-m1` stop reading after 1 hit
- `cut` out the line number
- `tail -n +K` output lines starting with the Kth